# MVC form didn't post the parameter of Ajax dropdown list

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My MVC form didn't  post the parameter of Ajax dropdownlist. The first dropdownlist works well but the second dropdownlist with tags doesn't send any parameter in my code and in debug it's still null.

View HTML:

```
 @using ((Html.BeginForm("SuppliesForm", "Supplies", FormMethod.Post, new { id="myform"})))
{
<div class="labelme">
                    <label for="BusinessClassID">ازکلاس</label>
                </div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BusinessClassID, Model.BusinessClassesList, new { id = "BusinessClassID" })
                <br />
                <select id="BusinessObjectID" name="BusinessObjectID">
                    <option value="-1">به</option>
                </select>
}
```

View Ajax and jQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#BusinessObjectID").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#BusinessClassID").change(function () {
            if ($("#BusinessClassID").val() == "d00717d5-ade6-4b4f-be0c-5e9b22f40391")
            {
                $(function () {
                    //var Data = JSON.stringify({ BusinessObjectID: $("#BusinessObjectID").val() });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: BaseUrl + "/BPMS/api/BusinessList/list1",
                        //data: { BusinessObjectID: $("#BusinessObjectID").val() },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType:"json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var option1 = $('#BusinessObjectID');
                            $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                                option1.append('<Option value="' + item.EventID + '">' + item.EventName + '</Option>').val();
                            })
                            $("#BusinessObjectID").prop("disabled", false);
                            $('#BusinessObjectID').append(option1);
                        }
                    });
                });
                }
            });
```

Web API:

```
public class Data 
        {
            public Guid? id { get; set; }

        }
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public List<Event> list1(Data p)
        {
            List<Event> EventList = Event.Query("Select * from Events").ToList();
            return EventList;
        }
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SuppliesForm(BusinessSupply supply)
        {
                try
                {
                    //_BusinessSupplyList.Add(supply);
                    BusinessSupply al = new BusinessSupply();
                    al.BusinessSupplyID = Guid.NewGuid();
                    al.BusinessSupplyName = supply.BusinessSupplyName;
                    al.BusinessClassID = supply.BusinessClassID;
                    al.BusinessObjectID = supply.BusinessObjectID; 
                    al.Insert();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
```

Comment: this view have two dropdownlist first  @Html.DropDownListfor and secound is that ajax post it into select tag.....select tag that comes from ajax and jquery dont send any data...and in httppost still null... :(

Comment: You need to pass `Data p`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `data` parameter to your ajax post. So your `Data p` is null in your action.

```
var postData={}; //similar to new Data();
postData.prop1=value1;

  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: BaseUrl + "/BPMS/api/BusinessList/list1",
                    data: postData,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var option1 = $('#BusinessObjectID');
                        $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                            option1.append('<Option value="' + item.EventID + '">' + item.EventName + '</Option>').val();
                        })
                        $("#BusinessObjectID").prop("disabled", false);
                        $('#BusinessObjectID').append(option1);
                    }
                });
```